# how to set spinner at position 0 if the taken string data is null

Tags: android

how to set spinner at position 0 if the taken string data is null. I took data from json. but the results are null or no data. how can I drag if the data I took is null and dragged in spinner to section 0.

```
String genderData = new String(reqresultItem.getMetadata().getGender());
if(genderData.equals("MALE")){
   spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(2);
}else if (genderData.equals("FEMALE")){
   spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(1);
}else if (genderData.equals("null")) {
   spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(0);
 }
```

this code list spinner

```
List<String> gender = new ArrayList<String>();
        gender.add(0, "Jenis Kelamin");
        gender.add("FEMALE");
        gender.add("MALE");
```

and than this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.application.example, PID: 24584
    java.lang.NullPointerException: toCopy == null
        at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromString(Native Method)
        at com.application.example.Akun.DataDiri$9$1.run(DataDiri.java:590)
```

Comment: else if (genderData  ==  null){spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(0);}

Comment: Use `else if (genderData == null)) { ... }`

Comment: check for  genderData null rather than equals

Comment: Change `else if (genderData.equals("null"))` to `else if (genderData == null)`.

Comment: no work @SudipSadhukhan

Comment: no work @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: Initialize string like: `String genderData = null;` then add data like `genderData = reqresultItem.getMetadata().getGender();`

Comment: no work this code @SudipSadhukhan

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: no work @SudipSadhukhan

Answer (score 0):

See if any of the following two modifications work for you:

```
 else if(genderData.length()<=0)
    {
       spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(0);
    }
```

or

```
else if(genderData.isEmpty())
    {
       spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(0);
    }
```

Comment: try this  genderData.isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

```
    String genderData = reqresultItem.getMetadata().getGender();
    if (genderData == null) {
        spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(0);
    }
    else if(genderData.equals("MALE")){
        spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(2);
    }else if (genderData.equals("FEMALE")){
        spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
String genderData = null;
genderData = reqresultItem.getMetadata().getGender();
if(genderData == null){
   spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(0);
}else if (genderData.equals("FEMALE")){
   spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(1);
}else if (genderData.equals("MALE")) {
   spinnerjeniskelamin.setSelection(2);
}
```